# Are there any replies to Searle's philosophy of mind but Bennett's and Hacker's?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, cognitive-sciences, materialism, john-searle

For a term paper I am looking for specific responses to Searle's philosophy of mind (though it's hard to even call it that) as presented in *Minds, Brains and Science* or the paper *Consciousness* (2000).

The only things I have so far is the extensive work by Bennett/Hacker, as well as the shorter version *Neuroscience and Philosophy*, and several books by Eccles, who was familiar with Searle's views.

What I am looking for now are mostly papers, not books, that respond to Searle's notion of mental phenomena, rather on a philosophical level than on a neurobiological.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been a vast literature critiquing Searle's viewpoints, enough to be collected,
e.g.,

> *John Searle and His Critics*. Ernest Lepore and Robert Van Gulick, eds.; 1991. ([Wiley link](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0631187022.html))

There are also collected criticisms of his Chinese Room Argument; see the excellent [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_room), and this collection:

> *Views into the Chinese Room: New essays on Searle and artificial intelligence*. 
>   Oxford Univ. Press. 2002. (Oxford link)

You might also look at the spirited 1995 debate with Daniel Dennett:

> ‘The Mystery of Consciousness’: An Exchange. *The New York Review of Books.* ([NYRB link](http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/1995/dec/21/the-mystery-of-consciousness-an-exchange/?pagination=false)).